# How to fit an image on a uiview programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I added a uiview as a subview on a view controller programmatically (called contentView). I also added an image on that uiview programmatically. Every time I run the app on the iPad the image is stretched! How do I fix the image so that it fits the iPad screen but doesn't stretch the image? I know the `drawInRect` is what is stretching the image. So how do I fix that?

Here is my code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.contentView.bounds.size, self.contentView.opaque, 0.0);

[[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu image 2.JPG"] drawInRect:self.contentView.bounds];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();  

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

[self.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: Is there any reason for such complicated image assignement? `[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu image 2.JPG"]];` - this should be all that is needed. Creating new image context for this seems like an overkill.

Answer (score 3):

UIImageView has a property called [`contentMode`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622619-contentmode?language=objc) which determines how the image layout is handled in the view context. `contentMode` is of type [`UIViewContentMode`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontentmode?language=objc).

The default value is `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` which stretches the image without respecting the aspect ratio. I am assuming it is the changing aspect ratio that is causing the issue.

If you wish to scale the image, but keep the aspect ratio, you have two options:

1. `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`: This will show the image scaled to fill the view, but not clip any contents (if the aspect ratio doesn't match view size, it will show either horizontal or vertical bands)
2. `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`: This will scale the image to fill the view entirely, without any bands - this will result in content being clipped if the image ratio doesn't match the view ratio.

To set the contentMode on the image view in Objective-C, use the following syntax:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu image 2.JPG"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
...
```

You should not need to use the custom context drawing for this to work anymore (thanks to Losiowaty for asking me about this).

Comment: Will this work, if OP already created a stretched version of the image, by drawing it in a custom context?

Comment: Good point, forgot to mention that. I would imagine the OP can replace the custom context drawing. I will update my post to reflect how the image can be instantiated. +1

Comment: I understand. However, both will not work. The `Aspect fit` shows the vertical band and `Aspect Fill` clips the content like you said. I think the best solution would be NSLayout constraints - Trailing, Leading, Top, and Bottom layout constraints done programmatically. Any idea how to do this programmatically? I'm new to Objective-C.. So I appreciate the help.

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish if `Fit` and `Fill` won't do the job. Are you trying to scale up the image to fill as much space as possible? Or just have the image displayed without scaling?

Comment: If you can update the question with an example screenshot or sketch, it may help us understand the issue.

Comment: I am just trying to scale the image to fit the uiview (contentView) which is the same size as the iPhone/iPad screen. The image itself is portrait. I need the image to fit the entire screen without it stretching.. That's why I suggested constraints.

Comment: As Badhan Ganesh mentioned below, if you are trying to scale it up but it is showing bands or clipping content, the content view aspect ratio probably doesn't match the image aspect ratio?

Answer (score 2):

Change code as below

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu image 2.JPG"];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

[self.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `self.contentView.bounds` is not having the same aspect ratio as your **menu image 2.JPG** . For an experiment, please try looking at the **menu image 2.JPG**'s resolution. For example if it is 300x150, it's aspect ratio is **(300/150 = 2:1)**. Set your self.contentView.bounds to this aspect ratio and draw the image and check the results. It will not stretch.

Answer (score -1):

**Please add this Single Line of code in your project**

```
yourImage .contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```